# Array of hashes: Validate presence of Key-Value pair?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

running the command

```
Company.first.employees.pluck(:roles)
```

produces the result

```
[{"admin"=>false, "editor"=>false, "viewer"=>false}, {"admin"=>true}]
```

As you see, it is an array of hashes.

**How can I check if any of the key-value pairs contains** `"admin"=>true`?

I would imagine it working somewhat like this (does not work)

```
Company.first.employees.pluck(:roles).values.include?("admin"=>true)
```

The desired result produces `true/false` if there are any key-values with `"admin"=>true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = [
  { "admin"=>false, "editor"=>false, "viewer"=>false },
  { "admin"=>true, "editor"=>false }
]
```

*Does any element of `arr` contain the key-value pair `["admin", true]`?*

```
arr.any? { |h| h["admin"] == true }
  #=> true
```

See [Enumerable#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F).

*Return an array of the elements of `arr` that contain the key-value pair `["editor", false]`*

```
arr.select { |h| h["admin"] == true }
  #=> [{"admin"=>true, "editor"=>false}]
```

See [Array#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-select).

*Count the number of elements of `arr` that contain the key-value pair `["editor", false]`*

```
arr.count { |h| h["editor"] == false }
  #=> 2
```

See [Array#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-count).

*Count the number of elements of `arr` that contain the key-value pairs `["editor", false]` and `["viewer", false]`*

```
arr.count { |h| h["editor"] == false && h["viewer"] == false }
  #=> 1
```

*Return an array of the elements of `arr` that contain the key `"admin"`*

```
arr.select { |h| h.key?("admin") }
  #=> [{"admin"=>false, "editor"=>false, "viewer"=>false},
  #    {"admin"=>true, "editor"=>false}]
```

See [Hash#key?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F) (a.k.a. `has_key?`)

*Return an array of the element of `arr` that contain the value `true`*

```
arr.select { |h| h.value?(true) }
  #=> [{"admin"=>true, "editor"=>false}]
```

See [Hash#value?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-value-3F) (a.k.a. `has_value?`)

Comment: Wow Cary, this is a great answer. Thank you. I will be definitely coming back to it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
Company.first.employees.pluck(:roles).any? { |roles| roles["admin"] }
```

Basically: for every element in `Company.first.employees.pluck(:roles)`, check if any of them return `true` for `roles["admin"]`. If they do, the whole `any?` check returns `true`.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F

Comment: No problem! The `Enumerable` module is great :)